# Complete a Field on Create/Update of Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Good Day

I have a field for business name, I would like a second field to be auto filled on Save/Update. If the Business has spaces between I require these to be replaced with a dash.

Example

Business Name: ABC Carpet Cleaners (Input)

Business Field: abc-carpet-cleaners@domain.com (Result Needed)
*The @domain.com is just normal text*

Any Ideas

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a callback inside your model:

```
before_validation :fill_business_field

def fill_business_field
  self.business_field = "#{self.business_name.downcase.gsub(' ', '-')}@domain.com" if !self.business_name.nil?
end
```

Comment: Thank you - You are a Star!